# How to decide which design pattern best for the concept

Tags: java, design-patterns, class-design, class-diagram

How to decide which design pattern best for the concept.
Ex. Metro railway , ticket reservation,

Comment: There is no general procedure or algorithm for deciding which is best.  Indeed, often there is not even an objectively correct answer.  But finally, you don't use design patterns for concepts ... or real world things.  You use design patterns for program designs; i.e. when you are trying to write a program to **do** something.

Comment: How to practice the design patterns for program design.

Comment: By practicing; i.e. by doing it.

Comment: Could you please share some resources or materials for practice with real time problem

Comment: That question is off-topic.  But try this Q&A - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79260/how-can-i-practice-design-patterns-and-refactoring-in-a-deliberate-way.  Or Google for "design pattern practice questions"

Answer (score 0):

*How to design* is a better (or perhaps the right) question rather than *which design pattern*. First, try to get the concept in more detail. Then try to apply object-oriented (oo) analysis and  design principles to understand and develop the concept in terms of object design. In the process one comes to identify and apply design patterns. Design patterns is just as aspect in the object-oriented analysis, design and development process. Not just *oo* - it can be any software design; and also in general.

Without more details about the concept and what one intends to do with it further - clearly - there is no way to think further, much. One can imagine only.